# Include line break in two line text zend pdf

Tags: php, magento, pdf, zend-framework

I have two lines of text from Magento's static block which I need to include in pdf. Im using zend php pdf functions.

Can anyone tell me how to bring about the line break btw two lines.

```
 protected function financeAdvert($page){
            $finance_advert = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pdf_advert')->toHtml(); 
            $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
            $page->setFont($font, 8);
            $fin_ad[]= wordwrap($finance_advert,50,'<br>',true);
            $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Html('#000000'))->drawText(strip_tags($fin_ad), 70, 245, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is

```
 protected function financeAdvert($page){

            $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
            $page->setFont($font, 8);
            $finance_advert = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pdf_advert')->toHtml(); 
            $yPos = 245;
            foreach (explode('|', $finance_advert) as $str) {
                foreach (Mage::helper('core/string')->str_split($str, 100, true, true) as $part) {
                    $fin_advert[] = $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Html('#000000'))->drawText(strip_tags($part), 50, $yPos, 'UTF-8');
                     foreach ($fin_advert as $yPosition){
                        $yPos-=10;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

This brings about a line break after every 100 char when it spots "|" symbol.